# How to make a proper release build - Unity Android - x86, ARM32, ARM64

Tags: unity, android, google-play

I'm trying to create a release on Google Play.

I currently have `Build App Bundle` checked in the build settings, and it helps decrease the build size.

In player settings I've `IL2CPP` set as the scripting backend, and  `x86` + `ARM32` + `ARM64` checked as target architectures.

Once built it creates `*-symbols.zip` in addition to just
`aab`.

My questions are,

- Do I need `x86` + `ARM32` + `ARM64` all checked? (I want to comply with [Google's new 64-bit requirement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html))
- Can I build split aab's similar to 'split APKs by target architecture'? If so can I have the same version code for aab's which targets different architectures? Is there any advantage of doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Google’s requirement is only for ARM64 support. You don’t need x86.

You do not normally split aab files. The aab has all of the architectures in it, and it is split into the correct apk by the Play Store, based on what device is downloading it. You can use bundletool to generate an apk to test with, or you can upload it to the Play Store and set it to alpha/internal testing to test the splitting when actually downloaded.

Normally during testing though, it’s recommended to just build an apk, as it is faster to build an apk than an aab and then an apk from that.

Comment: Thanks. Again to clarify do I need to check ARM32 or ARM64 or both, when when uploading an aab to Play Store?

Comment: Both (if you want to support both architectures)

Comment: I uncheked `x86`. But when uploaded to Google Play, this is what I get `Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices`

Comment: Google does not require support for x86, but if you already released the game with support for it, there’s no reason to remove it, unless you are adding a native library which doesn’t come with x86 support.

Comment: No I didn't release the game. I think I'd add support for x86 as it seems still some limited number of devices use it. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202022

Comment: Yeah, there's not a compelling reason to support x86 Android devices, but since Unity does it "for free" there's not a huge reason _not_ to if you're using aab files anyway, other than the necessity for support if somebody on an x86 device complains about it not working.